# Редирект в flask работает некорректно

Tags: python, nginx, docker, flask, docker-compose

Разрабатываю проект на flask + docker. Докер запускает следующие сервисы: mysql + nginx + crm + api. api и crm это два отдельных приложения flask. Настроил nginx так чтобы сайт открывался на 80 порту, то есть вообще без порта в адресной строке. Мне так проще разрабатывать + так проще выкатывать на проду как мне кажется.

Проблема в том, что когда в приложении flask делаю редирект `return redirect('index')`, то меня редиректит не на index а на `crm.flowito.ru%2Ccrm.flowito.ru` (flowito.ru это servername проекта). Хотя когда в докере прописываю внешние порты для контейнера, и открываю приложения не через nginx (то есть не на 80 порту, а на 5000 допустим) то редирект работает корректно. Ниже приложил код докер компоуза и нджинкса. Надеюсь на помощь. С такой проблемой сталкиваюсь впервые, по этому и не знаю как гуглить.

Заранее спасибо!

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:8.0.19
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_DB: $MYSQL_DATABASE
      MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - "${MYSQL_PORT}:${MYSQL_PORT}"
    expose:
      - $MYSQL_PORT
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - app-network

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: "nginx:1.13.5"
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - phpmyadmin
      - api
      - marketplace
      - crm
      - admin_panel
    networks:
      - app-network

  api:
    container_name: api
    build: ./services/api
    command: python start.py
    restart: unless-stopped    
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: start.py
      DEBUG_MODE: $DEBUG_MODE
      SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI: "${MYSQL_DRIVER}://${MYSQL_USER}:${MYSQL_PASSWORD}@mysql:${MYSQL_PORT}/${MYSQL_DATABASE}?charset=utf8"
      SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS: $SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS
    ports:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - ./services/api:/api
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - app-network

  crm:
    container_name: crm
    build: ./services/crm
    command: python start.py
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: start.py
      DEBUG_MODE: $DEBUG_MODE
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./services/crm:/crm
      - ./modules:/modules
    depends_on:
      - api
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: local

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**Конфиг nginx**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.flowito.ru;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host                 $http_host;

        proxy_pass http://api;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name crm.flowito.ru;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host                 $http_host;

        proxy_pass http://crm:5000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Хотел уточнить, зачем дважды устанавливается заголовок `Host`? Возможно стоит попробовать установить заголовок `Referer` как `localhost`? Или даже `Host`

Comment: `%2C` это запятая. Так Flask распарсил два заголовка `Host`. Уберите второй `proxy_set_header Host` и должно стать хорошо.

Comment: @AlexeyTen большое спасибо! Помогло)